# Use Helvetica variants on website

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I have to do a website that use a variant of Helvetica that is 65Medium. It's a variant of Helvetica Neue but it's Helvetica Neue. I'm not sure that I'm clear but I have to use Helvetica Neue 65Medium.

How can I do that in CSS ?

Thank you

Comment: Follow the instructions: https://www.fonts.com/web-fonts/instructions

Answer (score 1):

Helvetica Neue is not a web-safe type, so to do this you would have to license the typeface from a foundry like https://myfonts.com. They usually will allow you to use the type for a monthly fee and give you a CSS `@font-face` to link it to an external site.

An alternative would be use a similar free type from https://fonts.google.com/, but there is nothing quite like Helvetica Neue.

If you are looking for something quick, easy, and cheap I would suggest a fontstack that relies on Helvetica Neue for supported devices and fallsback on Arial for non-supported devices.

```
body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Hello thank you for the answer but I have bought the font.

Answer (score -1):

Declare it in CSS like so:

`@font-face { font-family: Helvetica; font-weight: 650; src: url('helvetica65.woff'); }`

And use it like:
`p { font-family: Helvetica; font-weight: 650; }`

Then, whenever you use Helvetica with weight 650, it will pull the Helvetica 65 `woff` file (you don't have to use `woff` as the file format, but it's recommended for web and pretty [easy to convert](https://andrewsun.com/tools/woffer-woff-font-converter/) into).

You could also name your font family however you like and not use the font-weight at all:

`@font-face { font-family: Helvetica65; src: url('helvetica65.woff'); }`